# Determine $[ \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2}, e^{2\pi i/3}) : \mathbb{Q}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I want to determine $[ \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2}, e^{2\pi i/3}) : \mathbb{Q}]$.  I can see that $[ \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$ because $2$ is the degree of the polynomial $x^2 -2$, which is used because it has $\sqrt{2}$ as a root.  However, I don't know what to do with determine $e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can verify that $e^{2i\pi/3}$ is a cube [root of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity), from which we can deduce that $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x^3-1}{x-1} = x^2 + x + 1$ is its minimal polynomial.  If $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$—or, equivalently, if $f$ has no roots in this field—then the extension $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, e^{2i\pi/3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ will be of degree $2$.  To see that roots of $f$ do not exist in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, note that these roots are complex with nonzero imaginary component (look at its discriminant or expand the cube roots of unity according to [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)).

To finish up, apply the [multiplicativity formula for degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees) on the tower $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, e^{2i\pi/3})$.